# accessing /var/log/audit/audit.log without root password

Tags: security, audit

**under RHEL 7.8**

```
drwxr-xr-x.   20 root root   4096 May  1 11:13       var

drwxr-xr-x.   24 root root   4096 Sep 27 03:22       log

drwx------.    2 root root   4096 Sep  2 03:34       audit

-rw-------.    1 root root  80765572 Sep 30 17:40    audit.log
```

Based on the file permissions of `/var/log/audit/audit.log` is it possible and if so how to allow a local user on that system to do *auditing* and copy and archive the audit log without knowing the root password ?

> Individuals with privileged access to a system also subject of an audit by that system may affect the reliability of audit information by inhibiting audit activities or modifying audit records. This requires that privileged access **be further defined** between audit related privileges and other privileges limiting the users with audit-related privileges.

Answer (score 0):

is this a solution?

1. Edit `/etc/group` and create a new group, named *audit* having a unique gid
2. Add specific users, who do not have root access, to this *audit* group
3. edit `/etc/audit/auditd.conf` and change `log_group = root` to `log_group = audit`
   4, service auditd restart and observe

---

```
 drwxr-x---. 2 root   audit     4096 Sep 30 18:04   /var/log/audit

 -rw-r-----. 1 root   audit    43040 Sep 30 18:06   /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

I realize this may be stupid since the copied off audit log can simply then be manipulated.  I suppose maybe keep a root.root owned copy of the raw audit log along with an SHA checksum?  Otherwise who's to know any better if the audit user manipulated the log file?